Downgrading from Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
My development environment requires Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS at most and Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS can be found in official website. And I don't want to install from anonymous source. So I installed 22.04.4 LTS
I couldn't find any information about the last part of version number.
When I try to setup my environment I get a warning "This in not a supported OS." Before going further I want to fix this issue.
Do you have any suggestion?
I did some research and found that I can not downgrade major versions. Only thing that I can back-up and reinstall Ubuntu. But no info about the last part of version number. Is it possible to downgrade minor part and how?
If I can not find a solution and decide to reinstall Ubuntu? How can I find required version (22.04.2 LTS)? Official website directs to download page and there is not this version.
I am not a pro user and thanks in advance.

The release of Ubuntu is 22.04 LTS; with the .1, .2, .3 .. .5 only really showing level of updates/fixes installed with the number incremented on later RESPINS when new ISOs arethey're released.
As appears in announcements, such as with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

As usual, this point release includes many updates and updated
installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need
to be downloaded after installation.

so in effect you're asking to install an updated Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system, and then remove some of the security fixes.
You could download the ISO you actually want, ie. from https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/  however the moment you applied all security fixes to the system, it would update itself to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS  (ie. a fully updated 22.04 system)
I suggest you explore what you need, as 22.04.2 & 22.04.4 are both 22.04 systems, with different level of security fixes.
If you're after the 22.10 or 5.19 HWE kernel used by 22.04.2, I suggest you use either the GA kernel stack (5.15) or current HWE kernel (6.5 from 23.10) as the kernel from 22.10/5.19 as used by 22.04.2 is no longer safe online

Actually I am trying to install PetaLinux environment for xilinx soc and I thought this case wouldn't affect me. Supported OSes are given as "Ubuntu Desktop/Server 18.04.1 LTS, 18.04.2 LTS, 18.04.3 LTS, 18.04.4 LTS, 18.04.5 LTS, 18.04.06 LTS, 20.04.2 LTS, 20.04.3 LTS, 20.04.4 LTS, 20.04.5 LTS(64-bit),20.04.6 LTS, 22.04 LTS, 22.04.1 LTS and 22.04.2 LTS" in the ref doc. When I run the setup, get "WARNING: This is not a supported OS". My kernel is 6.5 now and really don't know this is related with kernel or not? Maybe it is better to ask to xilinx. Thanks for help.

My guess it the page hasn't been updated in awhile.. ie. all the 18.04 details I'd have just written as 18.04 (ie. 18.04.1 thru 18.04.6 are still 18.04 with or without various security fixes installed), and not listing >22.04.2 probably means the page hasn't been updated for newer (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded before that date anyway).

As for kernel stacks; Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice; with the default set by installation media.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS offers the GA kernel stack (5.15 for the life of the product) OR HWE (updates to 22.10 kernel [5.19] at 22.04.2, 23.04 kernel [6.2] at 22.04.3, 23.10 kernel at 22.04.4 [6.5], and final 24.04 kernel [6.8] at 22.04.5 - ie. HWE kernel changes)... but that can be changed post-install too (or controlled by install media used).  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details amd note OEM kernel options may exist too!
