ssmtp question 22.04.4 and 22.04.3
why I cant use sudo apt-get install ssmtp mailutils at version 22.04.4，but 22.04.3 can do it?
if I use sudo apt-get install ssmtp mailutils ，the error reason is "ssmtp is not available"

ssmtp is in the Universe repository. Do you have "Universe" enabled on the machine with 22.04.4? The point version (.3 or .4) doesn't have anything to do with this, so your "diagnosis" is wrong.

Does this answer your question? How do I enable the "Universe" repository?

The only difference between 22.04.3 & 22.04.4 is that the .3 has not had security fixes applied to it that would upgrade it to the later version once applied. Are you sure the issue relates to these security fixes??  as I suspect the issue is something else.  This link (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4 however installed systems upgraded week+ before that date, so the 22.04.3 system has not had security fixes applied since BEFORE week+ before 22-Feb-2024

If you're unsure about point releases; reading my answer on this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513145/downgrading-from-ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-to-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts/1513146#1513146) maybe helpful..   The difference is security fixes  (& if using the HWE kernel, possibly different linux kernels as the 22.04.3 maybe using the kernel from Ubuntu 23.04 that hasn't received patches for some time due to EOL status; where as with upgrades the kernel switched to kernel from 23.10 at 22.04.4 so security fixes still occur.. it'll move to kernel from 24.04 soon with 22.04.5)

How do I know I'm enabled?

It is also possible to just download the package and install it: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/ssmtp_2.64-10_amd64.deb.html

what's difference between "sudo apt-get install ssmtp mailutils"  and "sudo apt-get install ssmtp"

ssmtp and mailutils are 2 different packages.

if i use sudo apt-get install ssmtp，it's ok?
